# На какой кодировке работают современные ОС

Tags: кодировка, ассемблер, unicode, masm32, masm

Скажите пожалуйста на какой кодировке лучше работать например в windows 7,8,10, чтобы с кириллицей не было проблем, на ANSI или UNICODE? Ну или покрайне мере на каких кодировках основываются программы скомпилированные Embercadero RAD Studio, Visual Studio и т.д.

**Программирую на MASM.**

Comment: Delphi с версии 2009 на юникод перешел, C++ Builder вроде чуть позже.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unicode поддерживает все письменности мира одновременно (это ещё не учитывая кучу дополнительных знаков), а ANSI — только латиницу (расширенные кодировки — это уже *не* ANSI). Вот и делайте выводы.

Answer (score 0):

`UTF-32` или `UTF-8` Юникод конечно лучше.

Comment: По факту WinAPI использует UTF-16LE поэтому программе под винду проще всего все делать именно в ней, что бы не делать каждый раз перекодировку при вводе-выводе